# Trigger jquery animations based on url

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to be able to trigger animations based on the websites requested url. So for example www.site.com/index.php#houses

Then that would make a `<div id="houses">` fade in?

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$(function(){
    $(window.location.hash).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: the `window.location.hash` already contains a #, so it needs to be removed before using it `$("#"+window.location.hash.substr(1)).fadeIn();`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function(){
    var uri = window.location.pathname;
    if(uri.indexOf("#houses") > 0){
        $("#houses").fadeIn();
    }
}
```